# How to listen to a touch event in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to listen to touch event of a React Native view and do some action in the callback. I couldn't get any way of doing it in a simple way. Only workaround I could find is to use Pan Responder and use `onResponderGrant` callback. Wanted to know if there is a simpler way of listening to touch event, something similar to `onPress`.

Comment: [Have you tried reading the tutorial?](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.html) Especially the [Touchables](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches.html#touchables) section.

Comment: If you are looking to listen for touch events without having a visual feedback use [TouchableWithoutFeedback](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#touchablewithoutfeedback)

Comment: @Hariks I am using onPress and onLongPress to listen to press event. But I need to capture touch event, which is different from a Press. I know PanResponder lets you listen to touches and onResponderGrant can be used to check if a View is touched. But this is a quite a bit of work everytime onTouch needs to be handled. Wanted to check if there is a simpler way

Answer (score 5):

You can use `TouchableOpacity` as a `View` that provides touchable feedback. Eg

```
<TouchableOpacity
    onPress = {() => function()}
    onLongPress = {() => longerFunction()}
    style = {{these can be the same as a normal View}}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You can also use `TouchableHighlight` and `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, which provide a darkening onPress effect and no effect respectively.

Comment: remember to include `import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native"` to use this :-)

Comment: Ryan Turnbull, I need to capture only the touch event, press on the same View has a different functionality, which I am already using